# Event button edit, grid devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

When clicking edit, I would like to know how to get the ID of that row.

My intention is to attack the event, but I don't know what it is, I have searched the devexpress documentation. The project configures the grid settings by code, not by interface.

```
public static GridViewSettings GetGridViewSettings_ElementoSlotRel(string locale = "ca")
        {
            var sufijo = "ElementoSlotRel";
            var gridName = "gvElementoSlotRel"; // @EDIT
            
            var keyFieldName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.id_elemento_slot_rel); // @EDIT
            var controller = NOMBRE_CONTROLLER; // @EDIT

            Usuario usuario = Aplicacion.GetUsuarioActual();

            int colsMedium = 6;

            if (usuario.EsDeveloper || usuario.EsAdministrador || usuario.EsLogistica) colsMedium = 7;

            AspMvcUtiles.CalcularRatioAnchoColumnas(3, colsMedium, 0, out float ratioSmall, out float ratioMedium, out float ratioLarge);

            var settings = GetGridViewSettings_Interno(sufijo, gridName, keyFieldName, controller, locale);

            settings.EditFormLayoutProperties.Items.Add(itemSet =>
            {
                itemSet.ColumnName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.Id_Ubic);
                //itemSet.RequiredMarkDisplayMode = FieldRequiredMarkMode.Required;
            });

            settings.EditFormLayoutProperties.Items.Add(itemSet =>
            {
                itemSet.ColumnName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.id_elemento);
                itemSet.RequiredMarkDisplayMode = FieldRequiredMarkMode.Required;
            });

            settings.EditFormLayoutProperties.Items.Add(itemSet =>
            {
                itemSet.ColumnName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.id_elemento_tipo_slot);
                itemSet.RequiredMarkDisplayMode = FieldRequiredMarkMode.Required;
            });


            settings.EditFormLayoutProperties.Items.AddCommandItem(itemSettings =>
            {
                itemSettings.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Right;
                itemSettings.ColumnSpan = 2;
            });

            // GRID
            settings.Columns.Add(c =>
            {
                //c.Visible = false;
                c.FieldName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.id_elemento_slot_rel);
                c.Caption = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.id_elemento_slot_rel);
                AspMvcUtiles.ConfigurarColumnas(c, ratioMedium);
                c.Visible = false;
            });

            settings.Columns.Add(c =>
            {
                c.FieldName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.Id_Ubic);
                c.Caption = Resources.Global.col_centro;
                AspMvcUtiles.ConfigurarColumnas(c, ratioMedium);
                c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;

                ComboBoxProperties propertiesComboBox = c.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;

                propertiesComboBox.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s, e){ OnSelectedDispositivoCentroChanged(s, e); }";
                propertiesComboBox.DataSource = Centros.GetCentrosComboBox();

                propertiesComboBox.TextField = nameof(SelectListItem.Text);
                propertiesComboBox.ValueField = nameof(SelectListItem.Value);
                propertiesComboBox.ValueType = typeof(string);
                propertiesComboBox.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e){ OnSelectedDispositivoCentroChanged(s, e); }"; 

                c.Visible = true;
            });


            settings.Columns.Add(c =>
            {
                c.FieldName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.id_elemento);
                c.Caption = Resources.Global.col_elemento;
                AspMvcUtiles.ConfigurarColumnas(c, ratioMedium);
                c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;

                ComboBoxProperties propertiesComboBox = c.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
                propertiesComboBox.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s, e){ OnSelectedDispositivoElementoChanged(s, e); }";

                //propertiesComboBox.DataSource = Elementos.GetElementosComboBox();
                propertiesComboBox.TextField = nameof(SelectListItem.Text);
                propertiesComboBox.ValueField = nameof(SelectListItem.Value);
                propertiesComboBox.ValueType = typeof(string);
                c.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
                {
                    p.ValueField = nameof(SelectListItem.Value);
                    p.TextField = nameof(SelectListItem.Text);
                    p.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = NOMBRE_CONTROLLER, Action = "CustomActionsElemento" };

                    //BeginCallback, sirve para recibir el callback de OnSelectedDispositivoCentroChanged
                    p.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "DispositivoElementoComboBox_BeginCallback";
                    p.DataSource = Elementos.GetElementosComboBox();
                    p.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e){ OnSelectedDispositivoElementoChanged(s, e); }";
                });

                c.Visible = true;
            });

            settings.Columns.Add(c =>
            {
                c.FieldName = nameof(CNX_ViewElementoSlotRel.id_elemento_tipo_slot);
                c.Caption = Resources.Global.col_nombre_slot;
                AspMvcUtiles.ConfigurarColumnas(c, ratioMedium);
                c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;

                ComboBoxProperties propertiesComboBox = c.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;

                propertiesComboBox.TextField = nameof(SelectListItem.Text);
                propertiesComboBox.ValueField = nameof(SelectListItem.Value);
                propertiesComboBox.ValueType = typeof(string);
                //propertiesComboBox.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e){ OnSelectedDispositivoElementoTipoSlotChanged(s, e); }";

                c.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
                {
                    p.ValueField = nameof(SelectListItem.Value);
                    p.TextField = nameof(SelectListItem.Text);
                    p.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = NOMBRE_CONTROLLER, Action = "CustomActionsETS" };
                    //p.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = NOMBRE_CONTROLLER, Action = "CustomActionsETSOnInit" };
                    p.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "DispositivoElementoTipoSlotComboBox_BeginCallback";
                    p.DataSource = ElementosTipoSlot.GetElementosTipoSlotComboBox();
                    p.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e){ OnSelectedDispositivoElementoTipoSlotChanged(s, e); }";
                });

                c.Visible = true;
            });
    
            settings.CellEditorInitialize = (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Editor.CssClass = "text-uppercase";
            };

            int? idDispositivoEstado = null, idBloqueContrato = null;
            string descContratoGVA = null;

            Notif notif = ElementoEstados.GetEstadoPorDefecto(usuario);
      

        
            if (usuario.EsDeveloper || usuario.EsAdministrador || usuario.EsLogistica)
                settings.CommandColumn.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(ratioMedium);

            return settings;
        }
```

Since it couldn't get the ID, it tried using the element callbacks, but I still need the ID of the selected row.